# How to update one to many polymorphic relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

How to update multiple records in One to many polymorphic relationship?
I want to update the fields as a group, but how?

**Skill Model**:

```
class Skill extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'percentage'];

    /**
     * Get the owning skillable model.
     */
    public function skillable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
 /**
     * Get all of the skill's user.
     * @return MorphMany
     */
    public function skills(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Skill::class, 'skillable');
    }
}
```

[image: form fields]

Comment: show your table columns and model relations

Comment: and also what did you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do so:

```php
$user->skills->each(function ($skill) {
    $skill->update([...]);
});

$user->skills->each(fn($skill) => $skill->update([...]));

$user->skills->each->update([...]);

$user->skills()->update([...]);
```

I recommend the first three approaches. Because if there are any [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events), those will be fired. Model events won't be fired in the fourth one.

Specifically to your problem, you might want to do something like this in the controller:

```php
public function update()
{

    $skills = collect(request('skill_titles'))
        ->zip(request('skill_percentages'))
        ->map(function ($pair) {
            return [
                'title' => $pair[0],
                'percentage' => $pair[1],
            ]
        });

    $skills->each(function ($skill) use ($user) {
        $user->skills()->where('title', $skill['title'])
            ->update($skill['percentage']);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear friend for your help. I have several fields in my form with one name that increase and decrease dynamically. How do I do this based on the code you suggested?

Comment: Can you clarify that in your question?

Comment: my form requests:

`
"skill_title" => array:3 [
    0 => "bvk"
    1 => "test"
    2 => "sdff"
  ]
  "skill_percentage" => array:3 [
    0 => "2"
    1 => "66"
    2 => "99"
  ]
`

If the user deletes a field according to the image in the first post or changes its value, how can it be updated?
All title fields have a name skill _title[] in form.

Comment: @BehroozValikhani I have updated my answer, pls check whether that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use update method

```
// make sure you have the desired attributes in fillable array property in your model class
$model->related_model->update([inputs]);
```

if you write the relationship methods "related_method" in model class correctly you can
 use them as properties of your model and access their attributes or update them.